# Confirm doesn't works

Tags: javascript

I need to push new objects in my array . Every object includes properties (name, sName, age, occupation, and the show method, which displays all user information). Array is filling by user.  (prompt)
But I have problem with confirm. when i push 'cancel' it's still continues to work . here is my code.

```
   var staff = [];


   var askAgain = true;


    while(askAgain==true) {


      var employee = {
      name: prompt("enter the name of the  employee"), 
      sName: prompt("enter the sName of the employee"), 
      age: prompt("enter the age of the  employee"), 
      occupation: prompt("enter the occupation of the  employee"),
      show: function(){

        document.write(' employee:  ' + staff[1].name + ' ' + staff[1].sName + ', ' + staff[1].age + ', ' + staff[1].occupation + ' <br> ' );} }


      staff.push(employee);



     console.log(staff);



    window.confirm( "Would you like to go again?" );

    if (confirm == true){
        askAgain == true;} 
    else {
       askAgain==false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: how are you running this code?

Comment: You really should not use `document.write`. And using `confirm` is not such a great practice either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a single equal sign for [assignment `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2).

```
if (window.confirm( "Would you like to go again?")) {
     askAgain = true;
} else {
    askAgain = false;
}
```

You could asign just the value of [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm).

```
askAgain = window.confirm( "Would you like to go again?");
```

While you start to collect at least one item, you could move the `while` check to the bottom and use the confirmation directly without any variable.

```js
var staff = [],
    employee;

do {
    employee = {
        name: prompt("enter the name of the  employee"),
        sName: prompt("enter the sName of the employee"),
        age: prompt("enter the age of the  employee"),
        occupation: prompt("enter the occupation of the  employee"),
    };
    staff.push(employee);
} while (window.confirm("Would you like to go again?"))

console.log(staff);
```

Comment: Apart from this, the OP is checking the value of `confirm` as well; which is the native confirm function instead of the result of the dialog.